# Calling a Method to a List

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, webmethod

So i need to pass a list from this method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm> ReadAtm()
    {
        var AtmReadList = new List<SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm>();
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLAdb"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (Conn)
            {
                Conn.Open();
                string SQLReadAtm = "Select * from ATM;";
                SqlCommand ReadAtmCmd = new SqlCommand(SQLReadAtm, Conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = ReadAtmCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    AtmReadList.Add(new SLA_ClassLibrary.SLA_Class.ReadAtm
                    {
                        idatm = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("IDATM")),
                        District_Region = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("District_Region")),
                        Local = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Local")),
                        IsUp = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("IsUp"))
                    });
                }
            }
            return AtmReadList;
        }
    }
```

to a website table in MVC, but i'm having problems on how to go about doing this.

I can't pass the "return AtmReadList" to a List<> so i have no idea on how to do this.

Any way to do this?

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: what is the use of 2 `using()`

Comment: I'm trying to pass a list from that method to another project in MVC, I just can't seem to create the list itself using the data from that method.

Comment: Why don't you add the service reference in your MVC project, call this method of your service and get the list.

Comment: Also change the title of your post, Title is something else and you are asking something else.

Comment: I can call this method using "var model = Methods.ReadAtm();" but how do i then list this to a View ?

Comment: I have no clue what exactly your issue is, but by reading the above comment, I think what you are looking for is `return View(model)` in your action where model of your view is of type `ICollection<ReadAtm>`

Comment: I have 2 projects, one is C# project with Methods and other is MVC where the website is. We get the list of ATM's from the C# project but i'm not sure on how to pass this to the MVC project. If i do call this method how can i then list to the a View ?

Comment: The method you have shown is not declared in a way that allows it to be used as a `WebMethod` despite the attribute. I must be `public static` in order to be usable as a web method. I think you best bet here is to copy the relevant code into your `mvc` application and use it within that application. Otherwise you will have issues with authentication etc...

Comment: I already use other methods from this project with no problem.